# custom subject line based on form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with multiple check boxes. once the form is complete it is sending a email with php. I'm trying to have a feature in the subject bar so it displays

Subject: Option 1

Subject: Option 2

Subject: Option 1 and Option 2

```
if (empty($_POST["CheckboxGroup1"]) || empty($_POST["CheckboxGroup2"])) { 
"$displaythis = '';"; }
else { "$displaythis = ' and ';"; }
```

Something is wrong but I don't know where. Any tips? Thanks

```
$emailSubject = $_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] . $displaythis . $_POST['CheckboxGroup2'];
```

Comment: Probably because you have this `"$displaythis = ' and ';";` instead of this: `$displaythis = ' and ';`

Comment: Your double quotes (`"`) are breaking your code. You'd see that if you had error reporting on - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: And you should really consider escaping those $_POST values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the double quotes:

```
if (empty($_POST["CheckboxGroup1"]) || empty($_POST["CheckboxGroup2"])) { $displaythis = ''; }
else { $displaythis = ' and '; }
```